# JWT The token could not be parsed from the request only on live site

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, jwt, apache2

I have built a custom API using PHP (version 7.0), specifically the Laravel framework (version 5.5.40) that uses the tymon/jwt-auth (version 1.0.0-rc.2) package for user authorization. Many of my controller functions use this line to get the currect user's credentials:

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

I use Postman to test my api.

When I make api calls in my local environment, the authorization passes normally and returns the expected data.
When I make api calls to my live site API (hosted in my apache server), I get this error:

*The token could not be parsed from the request*

Since this error only occurs on my live API, I speculated that there is a problem with my API's .htaccess file (which is by the way recognized normally by the application, I did some debugging and checked my apache error_log to make sure changes to my API's .htaccess are recognized).
I tried adding these lines (and different variations of these lines as I encountered multiple suggestions while researching):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

but still the error persists.
I tried adding this code:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

prior to the:

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

and I noticed that on my live API these elements are missing from the $_SERVER array:
**REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION, HTTP_AUTHORIZATION**

Wasn't the above .htaccess code meant to add these manually?

These are my Response Headers as seen in Chrome DevTools:

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** http:/example.gr

**Cache-Control:** no-cache, private

**Connection:** close

**Content-Encoding:** gzip

**Content-Type:** application/json

**Date:** Tue, 14 May 2019 11:33:10 GMT

**Server:** Apache

**Transfer-Encoding:** chunked

**Vary:** Origin,Accept-Encoding

**X-RateLimit-Limit:** 60

**X-RateLimit-Remaining:** 59

And these are my Request Headers (provisional headers shown):

**Accept:** application/json, text/plain, */*

**Authorization:** Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9hcGkudjIucmVzY2FwZXIuaG9uZXN0cGFydG5lcnMuZ3JcL2FwaVwvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1NTc4MzM1ODksImV4cCI6MTY0NDIzMzU4OSwibmJmIjoxNTU3ODMzNTg5LCJqdGkiOiJweDRjNDlOckFQbGMyM21OIiwic3ViIjo1LCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIn0.YWPhPDeNrB4TI1gdhBYylrmIAs1-r1-K2M2eKyO89KY

**Origin:** http://example.gr

**Referer:** http://example/summary

**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36

EDIT:
This is the virtual host configuration of the production server for this specific domain as found in the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost |example-ip|:80>
  ServerName api.example.gr
    ServerAlias www.api.example.gr
  DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/api/public
  ServerAdmin webmaster@api.example.gr
  UseCanonicalName Off

  ## User example # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        <IfModule !mod_passenger.c>
          UserDir enabled example
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "/home/example/public_html/api/public">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>



  <IfModule suphp_module>
    suPHP_UserGroup example example
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup example example
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid example example
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID example example
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerUser example
    PassengerGroup example
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/public_html/api/public/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>





  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/example/api.example.gr/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1|example-ip|:443>
  ServerName api.example.gr
  ServerAlias www.api.example.gr
  DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/api/public
  ServerAdmin webmaster@api.example.gr
  UseCanonicalName Off

  ## User example # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        <IfModule !mod_passenger.c>
          UserDir enabled example
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/home/example/public_html/api/public">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>


  <Proxymatch ^https?://127\.0\.0\.1:(2082|2083|2077|2078|2079|2080|2086|2087|2095|2096)/>
       <IfModule security2_module>
          SecRuleEngine Off
       </IfModule>
  </Proxymatch>

  <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup example example
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup example example
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid example example
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID example example
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerUser example
    PassengerGroup example
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/public_html/api/public/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/api.example.gr/combined

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    <Directory "/home/example/public_html/api/public/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>




  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/example/api.example.gr/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

It should be noted that my actual API's ip and domain haven been replaced with example ones:

**front url:** http://example.gr

**api url:** http://api.example.gr

Comment: As you can see the problem lies somewhere in the apache configuration. On your local machine the headers exist, but on the production server they are missing. Can you paste the virtual host configuration if you have access to those files.

Comment: @DilyanTrayanov Hey there, I edited my answer by adding the virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM FINALLY SOLVED! It was a permissions problem. I defaulted everything to 755 for folders and 644 for files and the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION headers appeared.

Answer (score 1):

It seems apache is removing the authorization header. So try this

from

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

The regex expression is a bit different. This configuration is direct copy/paste from the default .htaccess from symfony/apache-pack which you can find here
[symfony/apache-pack](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/symfony/apache-pack/1.0)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it didn't work. I also tried this solution to no avail:

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

Comment: @IliasTsouchlos You still have no authorization headers ?

Comment: Unfortuately yes, the var_dump I mentioned above shows me the $_SERVER table in the production environment for the specific API call i am making and no authorization headers exist there